# How can I reset PhpStorm to import classes again?

Tags: php, phpstorm, preferences

I fiddled with PhpStorm's settings and now my "import class" function at `__construct` has disappeared. There used to be a little yellow bulb there and you could then import the class. Maybe some PSR stuff? I have no idea at all.

*This is a non working example.*

```php
class someClass extends baseController() {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Article = new App\Article\Article();
    }

}
```

would become

```php
use App\Article\

class someClass extends baseController() {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Article = new Article();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would start by checking the list of disabled inspections, this one specifically:
"Inspections | PHP | Undefined symbols | Undefined class"

Any chance that you have it disabled?

Comment: Under `Settings/Preferences | Directories` the Path to the App was missing. Solved by myself but thanks to the Heads Up @duck_in_hat

Comment: @KarlosBoll Consider answering your own question then (you can mark it as accepted later). This will help other users in a similar situation (since a question with accepted answer is more "visible" and has better chance to be viewed/discovered). Just a couple of lines of text + a screenshot probably (to better describe what what missing and where -- having images always helps).